# Android: How to pick multiple contacts

Tags: android

I'm using this code to let the user choose a contact:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 1001);
```

but what I want to do is to let hime choose multiple contacts (with checkboxes).
How can I do this ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/1gravity/Android-ContactPicker (I'm the author)

Comment: works great still

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with the ACTION_PICK intent option.  To implement this, you'll need to use a custom ListView with contacts generated from a query to the contacts content provider.

If you want to use the `Intent.ACTION_PICK` intent, you'll need to tell the user to pick one-at-a-time.

**UPDATE:**

There are several ways to do this with a custom `ListView`.  The old way (that is compatible with most phones) is a bit lengthy to explain, but luckily there is a good tutorial [here](http://vikasdp.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/custom-android-listview-to-read-phone-contacts/) describing exactly what you're looking for (contact list with checkbox in a custom ListView).

With API 5 and above, there is a `ContactsContract` class that can help with getting a list of contacts.  For example code on how to use this, look at android's [ContactManager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html) sample application, specifically the [ContactManager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/src/com/example/android/contactmanager/ContactManager.html) class and the `populateContactList()` method.

The API for the `ContactsContract` class is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) as well.

Comment: Can you add code for doing this ? (voted +1 for the explanation)

Comment: @Belgi, I've updated my answer with several resources to get you started.  Personally, I prefer to use the Contacts query method (the first way as described in the linked tutorial).

Comment: Your suggested blog link "http://vikasdp.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/custom-android-listview-to-read-phone-contacts/" is broken now, please replace it with any another appropriate example.

Comment: suggested link not opening. :-(

Comment: Hey, the link is not opening...Do you mind updating it, or providing some code to help? Thanks so much John!