# Selecting multiple contacts on android

Tags: android, contacts, native-activity

I have seen this code segment for opening a native activity that chooses one contact

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 1);
```

What 
I'm interrested in is the activity used for messages
On android, when you write a message and press "`add recipient`"
u get an activity that chooses multiple contacts.

is there any hope to use that activity in my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to pick multiple contacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856422/android-how-to-pick-multiple-contacts)

Comment: Sorry if it seems a similar question, but my point was to use the same activity used in SMS: "What I'm interrested in is the activity used for messages On android, when you write a message and press "add recipient" u get an activity that chooses multiple contacts.".... sorry again

Comment: hi himura..have u find solution for this ? thanks in advanve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple pick activity is not provided by Base Android so all OEMs provide their own implementation of the multiple pick activity, so i don't think you can find a general implementation common to all handsets.

Comment: Oh I see. OK, is there a way to program scrolling to make it perform like the contacts (scroll to letter "L" for example), and group list items according to their first letter (just like the contacts app)?

Comment: Hello, this was long time ago but I remember I have done it manually in the end of the day. got all contacts from the database, put them on a list view with checkboxes and so on. I believe I still have the code but it was for older android versions (2.3). It should work for 4.4 but maybe just not efficient