# Setting Button Click Value to a ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

I have been searching for a solution to this for a week and just can not find any thing that helps me with my issue. I have a button that lets you select a contact from your contacts list on your phone.
The issue i have that I have is I want that selected contact to be populated in to a list view and then repeated again by selecting another contact and then putting the contact under the list view again to create a running list.  This list will be used to send a mass email for the contacts selected.

Any direction would be great. Thanks.

Here is what I have so far...

xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectGuestListButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/selectGuestList"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectGuestListButton"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
    </ListView>
```

my code

```
 public class GuestListFragment extends Fragment {

private Event mEvent;

private Button mEventGuestListButton;

private static final int REQUEST_CONTACT = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mEvent = new Event();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();

        //specify which fields you want to query to return values for
        String[] queryFields = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,

        };

        //perform your query
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null);

        //double check you get results
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            c.close();
            return;
        }

        //pull out first column of the first row of data
        c.moveToFirst();
        String guest = c.getString(0);
        mEvent.setGuest(guest);
        mEventGuestListButton.setText(guest);

        c.close();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guest_list, parent, false);


    //guest list button
    mEventGuestListButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.selectGuestListButton);
    mEventGuestListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CONTACT);
        }
    });

    if (mEvent.getGuest() != null){
        mEventGuestListButton.setText(mEvent.getGuest());
    }


    return v;

}

}
```

Comment: Possibly this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856422/android-how-to-pick-multiple-contacts

Comment: i guess what i am not understanding is how to take the contact i select and add it to a list view.

Comment: This should help you get a hang of The same. http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/